# Eclipse Maven Errors when Importing Kafka Streams Examples

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

Am using Eclipse Oxygen.1a Release (4.7.1a) on macOS Sierra 10.12.6. Have Java 1.8 and Scala 2.12.4 installed as well.

Did a git clone of the following repository from Confluent:

https://github.com/confluentinc/kafka-streams-examples

When imported this as a Maven project in Eclipse, I got the following errors:

```
Plugin execution not covered by lifecycle configuration: net.alchim31.maven:scala-maven-plugin:3.2.1:compile (execution: default, phase: compile)

Plugin execution not covered by lifecycle configuration: net.alchim31.maven:scala-maven-plugin:3.2.1:testCompile (execution: default, phase: test-compile)

Plugin execution not covered by lifecycle configuration: org.apache.avro:avro-maven-plugin:1.8.2:schema (execution: default, phase: generate-sources)
```

Tried using the solution (installing Takari Lifecycle Support) suggested in this post:

[Maven pom error in eclipse with Scala](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32745952/maven-pom-error-in-eclipse-with-scala)

And I keep getting the same errors.

This dialog came up when trying to import as a Maven project in Eclipse:

[[image: Eclipse Error Dialog[1]]

Also, in my pom.xml file, Eclipse is displaying a curly red line under the `<execution>` tag inside this code snippet:

```
 <executions>
     <execution>
         <goals>
             <goal>compile</goal>
             <goal>testCompile</goal>
         </goals>
     </execution>
</executions>
```

And also:

```
<plugin>
 <groupId>org.apache.avro</groupId>
 <artifactId>avro-maven-plugin</artifactId>
 <version>${avro.version}</version>
 <executions>
     <execution>
         <phase>generate-sources</phase>
         <goals>
             <goal>schema</goal>
         </goals>
         <configuration>
             <sourceDirectory>src/main/resources/avro/io/confluent/examples/streams</sourceDirectory>
             <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/generated-sources</outputDirectory>
              <stringType>String</stringType>
         </configuration>
     </execution>
 </executions>
```

Does anyone know how to resolve this issue?

---

@AlexOtt - Yes, the other SO post that you gave indicated to wrap the  and  surrounding the  tags.

The Confluent code didn't surround it with all :

https://github.com/confluentinc/kafka-streams-examples/blob/3.3.0-post/pom.xml

Now, the errors are gone from the Eclipse problems view. There's a new issue but I'll create a new post since it doesn't pertain to the title of this question. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to solve "Plugin execution not covered by lifecycle configuration" for Spring Data Maven Builds](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6352208/how-to-solve-plugin-execution-not-covered-by-lifecycle-configuration-for-sprin)

Comment: Not sure of those plugins work properly with Eclipse. We recommend Intellij. Workaround: run a `mvn -DskipTests clean package`, and `mvn eclipse:clean eclipse:ecplise` in command line -- afterwards, compile error in Eclipse should be resolved.

Comment: @Alex Ott - yes it works after wrapping the <plugins> with <pluginManagement> tags. I edited the post to address your suggested solution. Matthias J. Sax - your suggestions unfortunately did not work.

Comment: You can always allow Eclipse to make these modifications - press "Resolve", and select "Ignore"

Comment: @PacificNW_Lover if you simply wrapped `<plugins>` into `<pluginManagement>`, then you effectively disabled their execution, as `<pluginManagement>` is used to declare plugins and their configurations, and actual execution happens when they are listed in top-level `<plugins>` group